# Read binary data with Node.js stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, binary

I'm trying to read a binary file with fs `createReadStream`. Assumed that we know the "misunderstanding" of `binary` and `latin1` as value for the `encoding` option, and that by defaults using `toString` on the `data` chunk will use `utf-8`, I have tried to user a `Buffer` and buffer concatenation that is the `.concat` function in this way:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream( graphPath );
                        var data;
                        readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                            var b = new Buffer (chunk.length);
                            if(!data) data = new Buffer (chunk.length);
                            else data = Buffer.concat([data, b]);
                        })  
                        readStream.on('end', () => {
                            console.log( "type is", typeof (data ) );
                            console.log("read graph %d",data.length);data.buffer);
                        });
```

so that to append the new chunk to the data. In this way the `typeof` object in `data` is `object`, but it seems the encoding it is still not a binary format (i.e. it is not `application/octet-stream charset=binary` to be clear in terms of content type.)

If I just do `data+=chunk` the output type will be `string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the data coming out of the file is already `'binary'` encoding, then set the `readStream` encoding to `'binary'` using [`setEncoding()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding)and concatenate all of the chunks into a single string and return that.  `setEncoding()` supports any of the encodings implemented in Node per [Buffer docs for Encodings.](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)

```
const getBinary = (graphPath, asBuffer = false, cb) => {
  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(graphPath)
  let data = ''

  // set stream encoding to binary so chunks are kept in binary
  readStream.setEncoding('binary')
  readStream.once('error', err => {
    return cb(err)
  })
  readStream.on('data', chunk => (data += chunk))
  readStream.on('end', () => {
    // If you need the binary data as a Buffer
    // create one from data chunks       
    return cb(null, asBuffer ? Buffer.from(data, 'binary') : data)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the input file is a `binary` file. The api method that takes its data as input is supposed to load a byte array: `public void importGraphDef(byte[] graphDef) throws IllegalArgumentException` (this is the api signature). Your code is correct, but for some reason that method throws an `IllegalArgumentException` error like the passed` data from `cb` was a nested object. I have used it like `getBinary(graphPath,true,(error,graphDef) => graph.importGraphDef(graphDef));` I must use `asBuffer=true` since it does not expect a string...

Comment: @loretoparisi, then if you always need the buffer then just remove the conditional in the return cb and the `asBuffer` flag. So your `'end'` handler would like `readStream.on('end', () => { return cb(null, Buffer.from(data, 'binary') })` and the `getBinary()` signature would be `let getBinary = (graphPath, cb) => {}`